# Onload jQuery event to call function and make it "live"

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

Exist any event in jQuery that attach an event like this:

```
$("body").on("click", "#test", function () {
    // some code here...
});
```

That I can attach to `load` or `ready` event, to replace the:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Some code...
});
```

I need this because I have the `$(document).ready();` scope in an external file, that do some form validation, and in my HTML I load some content by ajax, and then all is in that scope don't work.

In other words, I want that all in the `$(document).ready();` stay `live` on the page, using something like `.on`.

If I put the HTML directly in the page, without ajax, the validation works.

Any idea on how I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a suggestion:

Give global access to the validation function, then use the *AJAX callbacks* to call this validation function.

Comment: how can I do it? Never heard about `global access` in javascript.

Comment: @WellingtonZanelli http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9284273/global-and-local-and-private-functions-javascript

Comment: About variables it's ok, but what's about the function that I want?

Comment: @WellingtonZanelli `window.my_function = function() { /* code */ };`

Answer (score 0):

I assume element with id "test" is appended after ajax call.
then you can use like this to make the element ready.

you can add multiple document ready in a single file/ or in multiple javascript file.
but i would suggest you to put your code inside a function  and call that function from  the document.ready scope of external file.

```
function doSomething()
{
    $("#test").on('click', function(){
      //do some thing here
    });
}
```

**External file:**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
....
.....

try{
doSomething(); 
}
catch()
{
//this section will be hit when the method is not avavilble.
}
});
```

Comment: yes, its depricated in the last few versions. I misinterpreted your question.