# onclick and external js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

```
<p onclick="play()">abc</p>
```

js

```
 function play(){
    do something; 
 }
```

The above works if js code is in the same file as `p`

But saying:

```
<script src="index.js"></script>
```

index.js

```
$(document).ready( function() {
     function play() {
        do something; 
     }
});
```

What i get is `ReferenceError: play is not defined`

Other functions, except `play()` works well.

Comment: Have you tried removing the `$(document).ready(function() {});` if the javascript is within an external file?

Comment: thanks to everyone. solved

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  function play(){
        do something; 
     }
});
```

play() function is `local` to `$(document).ready(function(){` not `global`

Don't wrap your play function in `$(document).ready(function(){`  to keep it's scope global .

```
function play(){
    do something; 
}
```

Read [Global and Local and Private Functions (Javascript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9284273/global-and-local-and-private-functions-javascript)

and [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/javascript-variable-scope)

Answer (score 3):

This is due to scope.

`play()` isn't visible at that level, due to it being wrapped inside your `$(document).ready` function.

Answer (score 1):

No need to place it in `$(document).ready( function() {..}`

just mention it in your `index.js` as

```
function play(){
  do something; 
}
```

remove `$(document).ready( function() {`